# How do I use multiple classes with one ID selector?

Tags: html, css, class

I want this to happen:

```
.category-news #main-header {
    background: #001846 !important;
}

.category-sports #main-header {
    background: #001846 !important;
}
```

But instead of 2 lines of code, can I combine it into 1?

Answer (score 0):

Since IDs are unique in the document and have very high specificity any selectors before them makes no difference - so both of your selectors actually always select `#main-header` and can be safely merged into one:

```
#main-header {
    background: #001846 !important;
}
```

Comment: But I want the header to only change background when I view these categories. On other views, I want it as the default.